# Sending cookie with attributes using python requests

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm working with one pretty old server and for some reason it requires to send cookies in next format ([RFC2109](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) section 4.4). Raw `Cookie` header:

```
Cookie: $Version="1"; temp="1234567890";$Path="/";$Domain=".example.com"; session="abcdefgh";$Path="/";$Domain=".example.com"; id="00001111";$Path="/";$Domain=".example.com"
```

I know, that there's a way to implement that formatting manually using [prepared request](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests), but maybe there's some other method?

I'm using python [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/#).

Code *<s>which obviously doesn't work as expected</s>*:

```
from requests import Session
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from http.cookiejar import DefaultCookiePolicy

sess = Session()
sess.cookies.set_policy(DefaultCookiePolicy(rfc2109_as_netscape=True))
sess.cookies.set(name="temp", value="1234567890", domain=".httpbin.org", path="/", expires=int((datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365)).timestamp()))
sess.cookies.set(name="session", value="abcdefgh", domain=".httpbin.org", path="/", expires=int((datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365)).timestamp()))
sess.cookies.set(name="id", value="00001111", domain=".httpbin.org", path="/", expires=int((datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365)).timestamp()))

resp = sess.get("https://httpbin.org/headers")

print(resp.json())
```

**Upd.**

I've tried to set cookie policy to this old standard, but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I haven't found other way except using prepared request. Sharing my code for future researchers.

**Code:**

```
from requests import Session, Request

def dumb_cookies_request(*args, **kwargs):
    session = kwargs.pop('session') if 'session' in kwargs else Session()
    req = Request(*args, **kwargs)
    prepped = session.prepare_request(req)

    if len(session.cookies) > 0:
        cookies = ['$Version="1"']
        for c in session.cookies:
            cookies.append(f'{c.name}="{c.value}";$Path="{c.path}";$Domain="{c.domain}"')
        prepped.headers['Cookie'] = '; '.join(cookies)

    return session.send(prepped)
```

**Usage:**

```
sess = Session()
# some actions
resp = dumb_cookies_request("GET", "https://httpbin.org/headers", session=sess)
```